# strange SQL query results on MySQL for REGEXP match

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using MySQL and running follow query to get all column title starts with A, B or C. But my below query can still match title like Test. If anyone could give a hint what is wrong, it will be great.

```
SELECT title FROM customer where title REGEXP '[A-C].*'
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Do you need to get *only* the entries starting with *uppercase* `[ABC]`?

Comment: @stribizhev, yes starts with upper case A or B or C. Thanks for the ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a string start anchor `^` and use [`BINARY` with `REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) to enable case matching:

```
SELECT title FROM customer where title REGEXP BINARY '^[A-C]'
```

> `REGEXP` is not case sensitive, except when used with *binary* strings.

Note that `REGEXP` does not require a full string match, thus, you can safely remove `.*` from your pattern.

Comment: thanks and what is the most correct way to express not start with? I am using NOT REGEXP '[A-C].*', and seeking better solution from you.

Comment: [`NOT REGEXP BINARY '^[A-C]'`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp) is the correct way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `^` anchor to select all the text that starts with `A`, `B` or `C`

```
^[A-C].*
```

Also, you can remove `.*` from your regex.

```
^[A-C]
```

Comment: why need to remove .*?

Comment: @LinMa Not `need`, you `can`. As you're targetting elements that `starts with`, there is no point to check the characters after that